# What is ~/.local directory tree and two executables there?

Tags: user-account, folders

I find that something has added `~/.local/bin` to my `$PATH` and that the hidden `~/.local` folder has the following structure:

```
.local
├── bin
│   ├── alex
│   └── happy
├── lib
│   ├── aws
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── include
│   │   └── lib
│   └── python3.7
│       └── site-packages
├── share
│   ├── Unity
│   │   ├── 2018.3
│   │   ├── 2019.1
│   │   └── index-local.xml
│   ├── epiphany
│   │   └── localstorage
│   ├── folks
│   │   └── relationships.ini
│   ├── gnome-chess
│   ├── gnome-dictionary
│   ├── gnome-sudoku
│   │   └── finished
│   ├── keyrings
│   ├── recently-used.xbel
│   ├── rstudio
│   │   ├── addin_registry
│   │   ├── bibliography-index
│   │   ├── client-state
│   │   ├── console06
│   │   ├── content_urls
│   │   ├── ctx
│   │   ├── dictionaries
│   │   ├── explorer-cache
│   │   ├── history_database
│   │   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── log
│   │   ├── monitored
│   │   ├── notebooks
│   │   ├── pcs
│   │   ├── presentation
│   │   ├── profiles-cache
│   │   ├── projects
│   │   ├── projects_settings
│   │   ├── rmd-outputs
│   │   ├── rstudio-desktop.json
│   │   ├── rversion-settings
│   │   ├── saved_source_markers
│   │   ├── sdb
│   │   ├── session-persistent-state
│   │   ├── sessions
│   │   ├── sources
│   │   ├── tutorial
│   │   └── viewer-cache
│   └── telepathy
│       └── mission-control
└── var
    └── mathics
        └── mathics.sqlite
```

- **What is `.local` used for?** Do various apps just dump files there?

In particular, I can recognize traces of some apps there, namely, aws (command line interface to Amazon Web Services) and rstudio. But what led me to ask about this, besides now finding `~/.local` in my `$PATH` are two executables in `~/.local/bin`, namely, `alex` and `happy`.

- **What are these two executables?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the `.local` hierarchy, programs put user information such as emails and calendar events. You could manually remove this data, but then the program would lose its state

> .local is for storing user program data (like locally installed programs), not user data (like photos, calendars etc)

https://askubuntu.com/a/14536/168071

Answer (score 1):

`~/.local` is an attempt to provide a standard place to store executables and data for applications ported from Linux.  But, yes, it does seem like yet another place for apps to dump files.

In addition I have:

- `~/.config` used by Wireshark and iTerm2,
- `~/.Bin` used by Goodsync and TeamViewer,
- `/usr/local` and `/opt` which are Unix standards used by Homebrew and a few other apps - these are Apple sanctioned locations for system wide apps.

Even if there are multiple 'standard' folders, it is better than each app creating its own folder within `~`. I have about 25 of those, like `~/.dropbox` and `~/.julia`.  And even worse the apps that just put configuration files in `~` like the Apple supplied zsh.

Rather like all the stuff in `~/Library` (the Apple standard location) it is best to ignore these folders and just assume that the developers know what they are doing!

[Is this an answer or a rant?]